# Webscraping - Python - Can't find links in html

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all links from https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=sql&src=ukw&lang=en however without even selecting an element, my code retrieves no links. Please see my code below.

```
import bs4,requests as rq
Link = 'https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=sql&src=ukw&lang=en'
RQOBJ = rq.get(Link)
BS4OBJ = bs4.BeautifulSoup(RQOBJ.text)
print(BS4OBJ)
```

Comment: what's the link you expected to fetch? any example, I try your code and it gives me a lot html string back and it seems to be good

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't very clear.I'd like the course links so...   https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-sql-bootcamp/ etc

Comment: yeah I see... unfortunatly, the website is dynamic generated, that means it forbid simple web crawl by using ajax to generate part html contents. You could try CasperJs, which mock user visit other than crawler, I have one example for Facebook fan page, https://github.com/linpingta/facebook-related/tree/master/facebook-fan-page-fetcher

Answer (score 1):

hope you want link of courses on the page, this code will help

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

baseurl='https://www.udemy.com'
url="https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=sql&src=ukw&lang=en"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
courseLink = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "card__title",'href': True})

for link in courseLink:
    print baseurl+link['href']

driver.quit()
```

It will print:

```
https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-sql-bootcamp/
https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-oracle-sql-certification-course/
https://www.udemy.com/introduction-to-sql23/
https://www.udemy.com/oracle-sql-12c-become-an-sql-developer-with-subtitle/
https://www.udemy.com/sql-advanced/
https://www.udemy.com/sql-for-newbs/
https://www.udemy.com/sql-for-marketers-data-analytics-data-science-big-data/
https://www.udemy.com/sql-for-punk-analytics/
https://www.udemy.com/sql-basics-for-beginners/
https://www.udemy.com/oracle-sql-step-by-step-approach/
https://www.udemy.com/microsoft-sql-for-beginners/
https://www.udemy.com/sql-tutorial-learn-sql-with-mysql-database-beginner2expert/
```

Answer (score 0):

the website use javascript to fetch data, you should use selenium